# How can i use the variable in the path for source directory and destination using groovy

Tags: groovy

`git1` repository have a folder named `sports` which further have subfolders and files inside it.I want to copy the file given by the output of `git diff` given by `command2`.

```
def command2 = "git diff --stat @{12.hours.ago}"
Process process = command2.execute(null, new File('C:/git1'))
def b=process.text
println b
```

Output of Groovy Console is `Sports/Cricket/Players/Virat.txt`.
Now i want to use this file path in `sourceDir` as shown below.

```
def sourceDir = "C:/git1/$b"
def destinationDir = "D:/git1/$b"
(new AntBuilder()).copy(file: sourceDir, tofile: destinationDir)
```

This is giving error as `Warning: Could not find file C:\git1\Sports\Cricket\Players\Virat.txt`
 to copy.

Comment: Besides that if you run this on Java 7 or newer which is very likely, there is no real need to invoke an Ant copy task. Just do `Files.copy(Paths.get(source), Paths.get(target))`.

Comment: The problem is with path of sourceDir and destinationDir as when i am providing the complete path then it is able to copy.I mean if i use "C:/git1/Sports/Cricket/Players/Virat.txt" instead of "C:/git1/$b" then it is copying .@Vampire

Comment: I have tried using normal java 7 instead of Antbuilder but it is giving the below error:-   java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <
> at index 42: C:/git1/Sports/Badminton/Players/Saina.txt
at example.main(copy using variable:19) @Vampire

Comment: Ah, that helped, now it's clear what the problem is. Please give me the output of `println b.getBytes('UTF-8')` for verification, then I write an answer.

Comment: output is [74, 101, 110, 107, 105, 110, 115, 102, 105, 108, 101, 10, 83, 112, 111, 114, 116, 115, 47, 66, 97, 100, 109, 105, 110, 116, 111, 110, 47, 80, 108, 97, 121, 101, 114, 115, 47, 83, 97, 105, 110, 97, 46, 116, 120, 116, 10] @Vampire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your comment with the byte array, the last character of the string is a newline character (10). This of course makes the path invalid but is not easily recognizable in the error message. Add a `.trim()` after the `.text` and it should work with both, `AntBuilder` and `Files` and on both, Windows and Linux. If you would have done it on Windows there would be a 13 additionally before the 10.

Another maybe even better approach would be not to use `git diff` as you do, as it is a porcelain command. Porcelain command as their name suggests are not stable and their arguments and output can change any time. They are meant for human usage, not for scripts. Scripts should use plumbing commands which are much more stable in input and output. With the respective plumbing command you might not have had your problem.

Comment: I have to use git diff command  anyhow as per the requirement in my project.so is there a way to copy changed files one by one.I mean lets suppose i get two files in the output of b then i want to copy two files.Is it possible?

Comment: Some points: **1.** `as per requirement` is not valid, because it is not correct to use it. `git diff --stat` e. g. abbreviates filenames if they are too long making it useless for automatic consumption. `git diff --raw` on the other hand is a plumbing version of `diff` iirc and there you will always have the full paths. **2.** Please do not posts new questions in comments, but create new questions. **3.** Sure, just split the string, e. g. with `b.readLines()`, then process the lines like `b.readLines().each { Files.copy(Paths.get("C:/git1/$it"), Paths.get("D:/git1/$it")) }`, no `trim` needed

Comment: The above method is giving exception as shown below- java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: D:\git1\Sports\Badminton\Players\Sandhu.txt ...@Vampire

Comment: Sure, did you ever hear of JavaDoc? You should read it. Add `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` as third parameter to the `copy` call and files will be overwritten.